# How can you map multiple tables to one model?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

If I have two tables with same columns, ex. a table called Toyota and a table called Honda,
how can I map these two tables with one model (maybe called Car) in flask?

Answer (score 3):

While you can [map multiple tables to a single class](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#mapping-a-class-against-multiple-tables), what you are asking for is probably better solved with [inheritance](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html#inheritance-configuration).  There are two main types of inheritance: joined or single table.  Since your example says that the type is the only thing different, all other columns being the same, [single table](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html#single-table-inheritance) seems more appropriate.

```
class Car(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    wheels = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=4)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type,
    }


class TeslaModelS2014(Car):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'Tesla Model S 2014',
    }
```

This is a really contrived example; inheritance isn't really appropriate at all here.  All cars can be represented without making subclasses.  If you have subclasses, you have to make one for each make/model/year in existence, which is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two tables with the same columns, your database schema could probably be done better. I think you should really have a table called CarMake, with entries for Toyota, Honda etc, and another table called Car which has a foreign key to CarMake (e.g. via a field called car_make or similar).

That way, you could represent this in Flask with two models - one for Car and one for CarMake.